# Iterating over a complex object using ngRepeat to generate inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Using AngularJS, I need to generate settings for a web app using ngRepeat to generate each input. An example of the settings object is as follows:

```
// in HostController where var host = this
host.settings = {
  section: {
    property: {name: "Option title", value: 1024},
    property: {name: "Option title", value: false},
    property: {name: "Option title", value: "#000000"},
  },
  section: {
    dropdownPproperty: {name: "Option title", value: "a", values: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]}, 
    dropdownProperty: {name: "Option title", value: "g", values: ["e", "f", "g", "h"]},
  },
  section: {
    group: {
      property: {name: "Option title", value: 0.9},
      property: {name: "Option title", value: 1.2},
    },
    group: {
      property: {name: "Option title", value: 1},
      group: {
        property: {name: "Option title", value: 0.5},
      },
    },
  },
  section: {
    property: {name: "Option title", value: false},
  }
};
```

Note that in this example the parts of the object have been named what they're supposed to be, eg section/property/group - therefore these names can't be used for identification.

The settings object is divided into different sections. All sections are on the first level of the object. Each section should have its own `<div>` at the very least.

Each property should have its own `<input>` - the type of input should depend on the value of the property (eg number/boolean(checkbox)/text).

If the property should be a dropdown (ie has a values array) then it should be a dropdown.

I'd like to ignore groups - the properties of each group should iterated over as if the group wasn't present at all.

I've used ngRepeat a good few times before but only ever to iterate over something simple - a task like this just seems to complex to me, I don't even know if it's possible. How would I go about this?

Thank you very much for any advice and/or help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a filter to exclude the groups like this
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter